# Jupyter notebook - Couldn't find program: 'bash'

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a PC with Windows 7 and a Python 3.4 Jupyter notebook from Anaconda3 version 2.3.0.

I'm attempting to run the cell magic `bash` command from a Jupyter notebook and am having problems that I imagine others will encounter as well.

From what I've seen in tutorials, it should be as simple as...

```
%%bash
pwd
```

When I attempt this, I get the error "Couldn't find program: 'bash'". This is true for other `bash` commands. I have also tried !bash and that has not worked.

A few strange observations that may help:

I am able to run bash commands that don't require parameters as long as they are the first line in the cell.

```
In: 
ls    

Out:
Volume in drive D is DATA
Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

Directory of D:\...

05/19/2016  06:25 PM    <DIR>          .
```

However if I put a return above the command, it seems to interpret the cell as python and gives the "name 'ls' is not defined" error.

If I attempt to call the `bash` line magic command `%bash` I get the below error:

```
'ERROR: Line magic function `%bash` not found (But cell magic `%%bash` exists, did you mean that instead?)'.
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Don't cell magics rely on the underlying operating system? If you are on Windows, then you probably do not have bash. Please see [this possibly related question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281910/ipython-notebook-bash-magic-error)

Comment: I having the same on linux. I get `OSError: "sh" shell not found`  when I try `!sh`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try what the error message said to try?

i.e. '%%bash' instead of '%bash'

[This page](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics) seems to indicate that you're going to want two percent signs to utilize the bash script magic.

Edit. Tailored answer to no longer be to specific errawr message. When I run %lsmagic I get the following:

```
%lsmagic

Available line magics:
%alias  %alias_magic  %autocall  %automagic  %autosave  %bookmark  %cd %clear  %cls  %colors  %config  %connect_info  %copy  %ddir  %debug  
%dhist  %dirs  %doctest_mode  %echo  %ed  %edit  %env  %gui  %hist  
%history  %install_default_config  %install_ext  %install_profiles %killbgscripts  %ldir  
%less  %load  %load_ext  %loadpy  %logoff  %logon  %logstart  %logstate  %logstop  %ls  %lsmagic  %macro  %magic  
%matplotlib  %mkdir  %more  %notebook  %page  %pastebin  %pdb  %pdef  %pdoc  %pfile  %pinfo  %pinfo2 
%popd  %pprint  %precision  
%profile  %prun  %psearch  %psource  %pushd  %pwd  %pycat  %pylab  %qtconsole  %quickref  %recall  %rehashx 
%reload_ext  %ren  %rep  %rerun  %reset  %reset_selective  %rmdir  %run  %save  %sc  %set_env  %store  %sx  
%system  %tb  %time  %timeit  %unalias  %unload_ext  %who  %who_ls  %whos  %xdel  %xmode

Available cell magics:
%%!  %%HTML  %%SVG  %%bash  %%capture  %%cmd  %%debug  %%file  %%html  %%javascript  
%%latex  %%perl  %%prun  %%pypy  %%python  %%python2  %%python3  %%ruby  %%script  %%sh  %%svg  %%sx  %%system  
%%time  %%timeit  %%writefile

Automagic is ON, % prefix IS NOT needed for line magics.
```

The following command works:

```
%%cmd
dir
```

buruzaemon nailed it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. I did try %%bash - that was actually what I tried first given that's how it seems it's supposed to work in the tutorials I've seen. Apologies if I didn't make that very clear above.

When I try that I get the error "Couldn't find program: 'bash'"